# Finding the number of occurances of a distinct value in a column

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I am exploring a new table in SQL and was wondering what is the best way find the count of occurrence of each value. In essence I would like to better understand the distribution of values in the column.

At first I did a select Top 10000 for the table and for this particular column I am interested in I get 2-3 differing values. Let's call them A, B, C.

But when I do a select distinct on that column I get 5 million separate values.

What I am wanting to do is know the distribution of the values in the column.

So an example of output from the query I am looking for being:

```
    Distinct Value of Column  Count of Occurrence
      A                               A lot 
      B                               A lot
      C                               A lot
      D                                1
      E                                1
      F                                1
      G                                1
```

Comment: Occurrence not Occurance!

Answer (score 0):

What's your looking for is "GROUP BY" :

Exemple :

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) FROM CATALOGS GROUP BY category
```

Will give you the number of element per category.